# Using grep in a if-else statement

Tags: shell-script

Why my code isn't outputting if a string entered isn't in the file. When I enter a string and it isn't in the file, there's no response back, it re-loops back to the beginning. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
while :
do
echo "Please enter a string"
read input_string
echo "Please enter the file name too see if that string is present in it - (Enter .abw after)"
read input_string1
if grep -q $input_string $input_string1 ; then
echo  "Your string has been found"
fi
done
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It was meant to say that a string which you enter, it looks for it in the file and it says if that string is present. I've now realised that I need to enter another bit of code for else. Thanks

Comment: `input_string` isn't really a speaking variable name, by the way :)

Comment: You need double quote around variable expansions. Read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 10):

```
while :
 do
     echo "Please enter a string"
     read input_string
     echo "Please enter the file name too see if that string is present in it - (Enter .abw after)"
     read input_string1
     grep -q "${input_string}" "${input_string1}"                                                                 
     if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
         echo  "Your string has been found"
     else 
         echo "Your string has not been found"
     fi
 done
```

Comment: I've just tried this code and it works thanks! I didn't realise that all my problem was with not having an else statement. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: You need to quote grep parameters. Think what would happen if my search string includes `-v`, or there are spaces in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You figured out your missing else-branch, but one suggestion:

instead of using `$input_string $input_string1` try `${input_string} ${input_string1}` just to make sure you don't get `$input_string` followed by 1.

Comment: No, your proposed replacement is exactly equivalent to the original. `$input_string1` is the value of the variable `input_string1` (split and globbed, since it isn't quoted), it doesn't involve the variable `input_string`.