# Using grep to locate string from a text file

Tags: grep

I need to use it to so the program asks the user for the text file and then the string located in that file. Then the program will tell the user whether the string exists in the file.

Comment: So what's your problem? Asking the user is not what grep does, it looks like your homework assignment includes some shell programming. (Duplicate of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156835/linux-using-grep) asked a couple of minutes earlier?

Comment: No, I mean I need to use grep in the program and the program asks the user what the string is.

Comment: yeah, so a duplicate of the other question.